# Can anything be done with the acorn dropped by trees?

Tags: minicraft

**This is a question about Minicraft, not Minecraft.**

I can't work out how to grow trees in Minicraft.

I to put an acorn in the ground after I use the "hoe" to prepare it.

Can anything be done with the acorn dropped by trees? Or is it just not implemented?

Comment: Stupid Minicraft with its name being so similar to Minecraft *and* having such similar gameplay elements that questions like this could be asked about either.

Comment: I just thought "there's no acorns i...oh". Minicraft.

Comment: i was already moving my mouse to click 'retag' when i read your comments, and realized perhaps its not a typo... (never heard of minicraft heheh.)

Comment: Hi. I added a diclaimer at the top of the qustion.

Comment: @Ender see http://notch.tumblr.com/post/14463117193/ludum-dare-is-a-wonderful-thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acorns can be planted right on the grass.  No need to hoe it.  Soon after, they'll grow into a full-sized tree.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to hoe the ground to plant acorns. Just plop them right on the grass and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Put them on normal grass and soon they'll be fully-grown trees. You can't plant them on dirt, sand and farm plots.